# Como retornar código de status da requisição Java RestEasy

Tags: java, api, rest, restful, resteasy

É bem intuitivo fazer um retorno da API com um objeto ou coisa do tipo, só que gostaria de fazer o retorno de um objeto juntamente com status code da requisição.

```
@Override
@GET
@Path("/{num}/{cod}")
public Foo getFoo(@PathParam("num") long numFoo, @PathParam("cod") long codFoo) {

    Foo f = new Foo();

    try {
        f = fooDAO.buscarFoo(numFoo, codFoo);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return f;
}
```

Dessa forma tenho o retorno do objeto, mas como retornar o objeto + o `status code http` para informar o resultado da requisição?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode retornar `javax.ws.rs.core.Response` no seu método:

```
return Response
        .status(Response.Status.OK)
        .entity(f)
        .build();
```

Comment: Simples e objetivo. +1